# Install fbmenugen: where are the perl-linux-desktopfiles and the perl-file-desktopentry dependencies

Tags: menu, perl, fluxbox

I found this nice script for generating the menu on fluxbox: https://github.com/trizen/fbmenugen

But for my needs I need to find the libraries `perl-linux-desktopfiles` and `perl-file-desktopentry`. Do you know How I can install them for ubuntu 16.04LTS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are CPAN modules for Perl, which can be installed using:

```
cpan Linux::DesktopFiles
cpan File::DesktopEntry
```

Information about the modules:

- [Linux::DesktopFiles](https://metacpan.org/pod/Linux::DesktopFiles)
- [File::DesktopEntry](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::DesktopEntry)

Comment: I wonder is these modules are available via apt packages as well or I will need to make them available?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/libdata-dump-perl/download  and install it with

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i downloadedFile
   ```
2. Download https://github.com/trizen/Linux-DesktopFiles, then click on Clone or Download, and download the zip.

   Follow build instructions on the same place you download the zip.
   Except add `sudo` in front of each command.

   ```
   dpkg --force-all -i ObmenuGeneratorPackage.deb
   cp -a /etc/skel/. /home/userName
   chown -R userName /home/userName
   sudo reboot
   ```

Now `obmenu-generator` should work flawlessly.